# Data Attr when active add class on another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, custom-data-attribute

I have data-slide-item.
I want to every time my button is clicked ('button') to check if 'success-item' is active and if for example 'slide-item' with data-slide-item="1" has class active, then give 'active' class to 'tab' with the same data-slide-item and remove on the rest.

Here is what I got so far:

```
$('button ').on("click", function() {
  console.log('going left ..')
  var myEm = $(".slide-item").data('slide-item');

  $('.slide-item').each(function(){
    if( $(".slide-item").hasClass('active') ){
      if ($('.tab').data('slide-item') == 'item-1') {
        console.log('one');
        $(this).addClass('show').removeClass('hide') ;
        //^^^^^
      } else if ($('.tab').data('slide-item') == 'item-3') {
        console.log('two');
        $(this).addClass('show').removeClass('hide') ;
        //^^^^^
      } else if ($('.tab').data('slide-item') == 'item-2') {
        console.log('three');
        $(this).addClass('show').removeClass('hide') ;
      }    
      $('.tab[data-slide-item = '+myEm+']').addClass('show').removeClass('hide') ;
    } else {
      $('.tab[data-slide-item = '+myEm+']').addClass('hide').removeClass('show');    
    }  
  });
});
```

Comment: please attach your html code.

Comment: @swathi_sri it would be something like this but slide-item is a slider to imagine that active class changes on each slide
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MGGXRo?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Finding it hard to understand your question.. however does this help?

```
//Remove all active classes from the tabs
$('.tab[data-slide-item]').removeClass('active');
// add it to the myEm item
$('.tab[data-slide-item="'+myEm+'"]').addClass('active');
```

Comment: not really. 
if you look into my code you will see that i'm checking if 
slide-item has class active and if so find a pair with the same data-slide-id and give a class active 9(to that element which is .tab).
right now that happens only on first item, but not when i click on my button again... Hope this make sense

Comment: Sorry I don't see where you are adding an active class, you do check for it, but don't add it. if you could add html, it maybe clearer.